# Can items inside trig functions be factorized? Eg, can we cancel $x$ in $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x}$ to get $\frac{\sin(x)}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The basics: Can items inside of trig functions be factorized? For example, can
$$\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x} = \frac{\sin(x)}{2}$$ by canceling out the common $x$?

It doesn't seem so based on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20sin%20%28x%5E2%29%2F%282x%29%20%3D%20%28sin%20x%29%2F2%3F). But why not?

Comment: Imagine doing that with $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. You would just be left with $\frac{\sin()}{1}$ and that is meaningless. The point is that $\sin$ is a function that takes in some input $x$ and spits an output $\sin(x)$. $\sin(x)$ should not be interpreted as the product of $\sin$ and $x$.

Comment: @Abhi Well, not $\sin()/1$: you would be left with $\sin(1)/1$.

Comment: The reason is that $\sin x$ is not a linear function; $\sin{ax} \neq a \cdot \sin x$

Comment: @Gae.S.I suppose that's more fair..

Comment: Just think about what happens when you say "Let $f(x)$ be a function......". $f(x)$ is not the product of the function $f$ and the independent variable $x$. $f(x)$ is the output of the function $f$ under a given input $x$.  

Now, you can do this sort of cancellation (mind you, the cancellation is only allowed when $x \neq 0$) if $f$ is linear. So, for example, if $f(x)  = ax$ for some constant $a$. Then, you're allowed to do this. If $f(x) = x^2$, then you're allowed to do that even though $f$ is not linear. In that case, you have to be careful that $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trig functions are not linear. Therefore you can't do this.
Linear meaning $f(ax) = af(x)$ and $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Here's an intuitive proof of why it can't be linear. Notice that $\sin$ is bounded, it takes its values in $[-1,1]$.

For a given $x \in R$, let's denote $y = \sin(x)$. Then if you had $\sin(ax) = a\sin(x)$ for all a, this would imply $\sin(ax) = a\sin(x) = ay$.

The right hand side can take arbitrary large values and the left hand side is bounded (between [-1, 1]).

This of course true in a more general context.

Comment: +1 Nice answer!